# How to set the value of checkbox to false in first run

Tags: java, android

How to set the value of checkbox to false in first run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initalise your checkbox in your activities onCreate() Method. Override onCreate() and do something like

```
  CheckBox android = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  android.setChecked(false);
```

If you want to know more about Android's activity lifecycle check out the Tutorial in the Android API:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#Create

There you have a full example for onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         ch.setChecked(false); 
         and
         ch.setChecked(true);
```